# C++ read line to class vector

Tags: c++, vector, concatenation, ofstream

I have next c++ class called "Contact":

```
class Contact
{
private:
    std::string contactName;
    double subscriptionPrice;
    int minutesIncluded;

public:
    Contact(const std::string &contactName, double subscriptionPrice,
            int minutesIncluded) : contactName(contactName), subscriptionPrice(subscriptionPrice), minutesIncluded(minutesIncluded)) {}
    Contact() {

    }

    ...gettetrs and setters
}
```

I have text file with one or more contacts in format:

```
asd,1.00000,1
```

In main method I have method that add properly vector of contacts in this text file. Problem is when I try to read from it. My target is to convert text file into vector of contacts. Method I use is next:

```
void phonebook_load(vector<Contact> &contacts)
{
    string line;
    ifstream phonebook_file;
    vector<std::string> lines;
    phonebook_file.open(phonebook_filename);
    if(!phonebook_file.is_open())
        cout << "Phonebook file could not be openned !!!" << endl;
    else
    {
        while (phonebook_file.good())
        {
            for (string line; getline(phonebook_file, line, ','); )
                lines.push_back(line);
        }
        phonebook_file.close();
    }
}
```

I have two options:

1. Read line by line (which I cannot split by ",")
2. Split by "," which print every property of contact on new line, and I don't see how tho handle it from there.

What should I change in my method in order to read file line by line and properly convert it to `vector<Contact>`

Comment: `fscanf(ww,"%s,%f,%d%*c",...) ;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide stream extraction and stream insertion operators for your type:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>


class Contact
{
private:
    std::string contactName;
    double subscriptionPrice;
    int minutesIncluded;

public:
    Contact() {}
    Contact(const std::string &contactName, double subscriptionPrice, int minutesIncluded)
    : contactName       { contactName },
      subscriptionPrice { subscriptionPrice },
      minutesIncluded   { minutesIncluded }
    {}

    // declare the stream extraction and stream insertion operators as firends
    // of your class to give them direct access to members without the need for
    // getter and setter functions.
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, Contact &contact);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, Contact const &contact);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, Contact &contact)
{
    std::string contact_name;
    if (!std::getline(is, contact_name, ','))  // use getline with a delimiter
        return is;                             // to allow whitespace in names
                                               // which >> doesn't
    char seperator;
    double subscription_price;
    int minutes_included;
    if (!(is >> subscription_price >> seperator >> minutes_included) || seperator != ',') {     
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
        return is;
    }

    contact = Contact{ contact_name, subscription_price, minutes_included };
    return is;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, Contact const &contact)
{
    os << contact.contactName << ", " << std::fixed << contact.subscriptionPrice
       << ", " << contact.minutesIncluded;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream is{ "test.txt" };
    std::vector<Contact> contacts{ std::istream_iterator<Contact>{ is },
                                   std::istream_iterator<Contact>{} };

    for (auto const &c : contacts)
        std::cout << c << '\n';
}
```

Comment: @TeodorKolev As shown, the `std::ifstream` of the file you want to read from.

Comment: @TeodorKolev Please, look at last few lines of the example in my answer. There a `std::ifstream is{ "test.txt" };` gets defined. Substitute your own filename and pass `is` to the constructor of the first `std::istream_iterator` used to construct the `vector`.

Comment: Sorry, yes I saw but it did not working, I am debugging now

Comment: Sorry but this did not return correct data. Maybe there is something wrong here if (!(is >> subscription_price >> seperator >> minutes_included) || seperator != ',') {     
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
        return is;
    }

Comment: @TeodorKolev Then please edit your question to include a input file and the expected output and the code you are using.

Comment: @TeodorKolev The data **is** correct. Use `std::fixed` to output the `double subscriptionPrice` in `operator<<()` if you want zeros after the decimal point to show: `os << contact.contactName << ", " << std::fixed << contact.subscriptionPrice << ", " << contact.minutesIncluded;`

Comment: I don't know it doesn't add contact in vector at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182231/discussion-between-teodorkolev-and-swordfish).